# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \sin(\frac{x^2}{n})$ is pointwise convergent for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the series 
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \sin(\frac{x^2}{n})
$$
Then I have to prove that $S$ converges pointwise.

**My attempt**:

It follows from the mean value theorem that
$$
|\sin(\frac{x^2}{n})| \leq \frac{|x^2|}{n}
$$
Thus for $x \in [-K,K]$ where $0 < K < \infty$ we have that
$$
\left| \frac{1}{n} \sin(\frac{x^2}{n}) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \frac{|x^2|}{n} \leq \frac{K^2}{n^2}
$$
where
$$
K^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
converges pointwise (I am not sure here whether I should just say converges or pointwise converges). Thus it follows form the comparison criteria that $S$ converges pointwise (should I then again first say converges and thus also pointwise converges)?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: I suspect you mean the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?

Comment: Oh yes. I am not always sure what the name is in English as my book is in Danish and I am just trying to translate to English.

Comment: You mean $\left|\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right)\right|\le\frac{|x^2|}{n}$.

Comment: Oh ye sure. That was a typo!

Comment: Would I also be able to use the Weiterstrass M-test here to conclude that $S$ converges uniformly. Thus also pointwise? I am a little bit unsure as I have been told before that the series I find must not depend on $x$ in this case $K$?

Comment: It's a whole new question whether convergence is uniform. I don't think the answer is obvious. (Also, your typo is still wrong!)

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall t:|\sin t|\le|t|$$ and

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\sin\frac{x^2}n\right|\le x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2x^2}6.$$

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't matter if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or if $x \in [-K,K]$ where $0 < K < \infty$? Would it matter if I wanted to use Weiterstrass' M-test?

Comment: @Mathias: what is the point introducing that $K$ when you have a straightforward formula ?

Comment: Weistrass M-test will be useful for uniform convergence on a compact.

Comment: I am not sure. It is an exam question in my Analysis course where the professor has given it as a hint.

Comment: The question is about pointwise convergence, Weierstrass is overkill.

Comment: The only reason I would use Weiterstrass M-test is that it makes the next question much easier where I have to argue that the sum function for $S$ is continuous. It follows from an important sentence in my book that if we can show that $S$ has a convergent majorant series that the sum function is indeed continuous.

Comment: @Mathias: awfully sorry, I forgot to fetch the next question.